# How to call correctly QgsMapRendererJob in pyqgis3

Tags: rendering, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to modify ma pyQgis2 code to run in pyqgis3.
That is custom application, that shows canvas with appropriate layers and settings and I can't refresh canvas with pyqgis3.

pyqgis2 code that did the work:

`ms=canvas.mapSettings()
render = QgsMapRenderer()
canvas.refresh()
canvas.zoomScale(10000)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()`

pyqgis3 I tried:

`ms=canvas.mapSettings()
render = canvas.refreshAllLayers()
canvas.refresh()
canvas.zoomScale(10000)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()`

I get empty canvas window instead of rendered map window. And python freezes.